# SQL statement converting to LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Okay...... SO I have a drop down list that work but i wont to spice it up adding more checks.... in the asp format i have managed to check date restriction but i need to count from another table results but in ASP not sure how to count.... Hes the ASP Version I made that works i've done an SQL On to Get an idea

Here is the LINQ version only thing don't work is the get number of tickets already assigned to timetable

```
var query = from table in db.Timetables
                        join tick in db.Tickets on table.ID equals tick.TimetableID
                        where table.Schedual_Date > DateTime.Today 
                        && table.Advance_Tickets > "NEEDS TO GET NUMBER OF TICKETS ASSIGNED TO TIMETABLE"
                        select table;
```

SQL VERSION

```
 SELECT 
 COUNT(Tickets.TimetableID) AS NoTickets, * FROM Tickets 
 JOIN Timetable ON Tickets.TimetableID=Timetable.ID
 Where timetable.Schedual_Date > (TODAYS DATE) 
 && Timetable.Advance_Tickets > NoTickets
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking LINQ equivalent for SQL query as below

```
SELECT * FROM
Timetable Timetable 
Where timetable.Schedual_Date > getDate() 
AND Timetable.Advance_Tickets >= (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tickets Tickets WHERE Tickets.TimetableID=Timetable.ID)
```

you can try

```
    var query = from table in timeTables                        
                where table.SchedualDate > DateTime.Today
                && table.AdvanceTickets > (tickets.Count(a => a.TimeTableId == table.Id))
                select table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .Count() function to get the count. In your case tick.Count() would help. for example,

```
var query = from table in db.Timetables
                    join tick in db.Tickets on table.ID equals tick.TimetableID
                    where table.Schedual_Date > DateTime.Today 
                    && table.Advance_Tickets > tick.Count()
                    select table;
```